# Screen width detection is not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, width, screen, explorer

I have the following script that i use to determine the screen width of the device accessing the page. This works for all browser except ie does anyone have any thoughts how or why this is not working?

```
function view() {
    var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");

   if (isMobile.matches) {
        //Do Nothing
    }
    else
    {
    horizontalview();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var isMobile = false;
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    isMobile = true;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ahhh! - jquery to the rescue. I should have known better. Thanks, that fixed the issue.